# Convert PHP objects array to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object

I retrieve image paths with the function get_all();. This get_all function retrieves images as an object. This object has the attributes name, source_path and date. I want my javascript to add images to a div. I have the following:

The instantiate.php includes files like Jquery and another JS file.

```
<?php
    require_once("../../include/instantiate.php");    
    $photos = Photos::get_all();
    $JSPhotos;
    foreach($photos as $photo) { $JSPhotos + $photo->source_path; }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var photos = <?php echo json_encode($JSPhotos); ?>;
        for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            create_image("../"+photos[i]);
        }
    });
```

This does not work. Anyone got a solution?
Solution in Jeroen's Post!

New Problem;

In the create_image function I set the class and src of the image element. When you click such an image I want an alert box to show up. I have checked if the class is set correctly, and I concluded that all images did have the classname "imgid". So, any idea why this dont work?

Script in the javascript part:

```
$(".imgid").click(function() {
    alert("hey");
});
```

Comment: whats the error you're getting?

Comment: Appearently the variable "photos" in the javascript part is "null".

Comment: thats because your just doing $JSPhotos +. theres nothing assigned to the variable

Comment: You should pass an *actual* object-graph to `json_encode` - what is `$JSPhotos + $photo->source_path` supposed to do? It's sure not creating an array.

Comment: So if I change $JSPhotos to $photos it should work? Because thats the array that contains the objects, right?

Comment: check the answer below by jeroen it should work

Comment: @user2014780 Perhaps, although it might also include too much data. There isn't a problem with (and I actually recommend doing so) creating an intermediate structure .. *if* it's actually created correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning anything to your variable.

You probably want:

```
$JSPhotos = array();
foreach($photos as $photo) {
  $JSPhotos[] = $photo->source_path;
}
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Thanks. I have done exactly that, but unfortunately I get broken images now. I have checked the contents of the photos variable in JS and its all "null".

Comment: @user2014780 Check your `$photos` and `$JSPhotos` variables. What do they contain (do a `var_dump()`)?

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Can't remember what the problem was though (short memory). But right now I have created a function that doesnt work. Can you please check the OP? I am sure you solve it in a second haha!

Comment: @user2014780 You would need to show the generated html or the complete function. Either way, I would recommend posting a new question, preferably with an online example to test with.

Comment: @user2014780 By the way, you probably need event delegation as the elements are probably not yet added to the page when you add your click-handler.